# Dynamics CRM records merge

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

When I merge two records, the result record's access team only contains the users belonging to the master record, and not the other record's users.

How can I do in order to have both records access teams users in the merged record?

Comment: Sounds like a platform bug, which entity ?

Comment: Or Probably per design ?  Since access teams are meant for temp access on records, PG team might have thought why to share the inactive record with more folks.. make sense? Raise a ticket with MS in parallel..

Comment: @Arun Vinoth thank you, it is the Account entity.

Comment: Done with a plugin, it wasn't so difficult to do.

Comment: Great, may be your answer ll help someone..